# Python if statements keep skipping

Tags: python, if-statement

To provide some context, I am looking to create a program that will encrypt and decrypt through the Caesar cipher, and I have created code for both of these functions that works quite well. However, when I try to conjoin these into one code I find that it always ignores the if statements I have in place and will always try to encrypt what the user enters. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 !?.`~@$£%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;:<>,/"
translated = ""

print("Welcome to Krypto! ")
decision = input("What would you like to do today? (encrypt, decrypt, info) ")
message = input("Please enter the text you would like to manipulate: ")

if decision == 'encrypt' or 'Encrypt':
      print ("Encrypt selected")
      #encryption begins

elif decision == 'decrypt' or 'Decrypt':
      print("Decrypt selected")
      #decryption begins
```

Comment: `if decision in ['encrypt', 'Encrypt']:`

Comment: Yes, click through to the duplicate answer, it does a beautiful job of explaining why  `or 'Encrypt'` is always true.

Answer (score 3):

```
or 'Encrypt'
```

This is always True

Comment: Thank you for the advice! This was very helpful